# How to echo text with indents

Tags: php, mysql

okay so i have a form field that you can click enter and it indents to a new line and once you submit that text it goes into mysql database and i wanted to know how can i echo the text with the indents?

example:

i enter text like this :

> "hello
>
> how have you been"

and it echos out like this :

> "hello how have you been"

php to echo code:

```
<?php if (isset($comments)) {
    while ($rowrr = $comments->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<div><p>" . $rowrr['comment'] . "</p></div>";
    }
} ?>
```

HTML CODE text field:

```
<form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return insert_value()">
    <input id="hidden_data" name="data" type="hidden" value=""/>
    <div id="showing_data" class="commenttext" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Enter" id="submitthis" />
</form>
```

Mysql Code to insert text field text:

```
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
    $var2 = urldecode($_POST['data']);
    $stmt = $dbconn->prepare("INSERT INTO photocomments (user_id, comment) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('is', $user_id, $var2);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `nl2br`?

Comment: yeah exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Would an HTML `<pre>` tag be useful here?  It preserves white-space and line breaks.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

Comment: its good but i'd rather use nl2br ill still upvote you answer thoo